# how to use $compile in angular2

Tags: angular

how to re-compile the HTML which is modified by other xyz library? Other xyz library adds some exra stuffs to DOM and now Angular (click) method does not work.

in angular 1 we were doing like  below:

this.$compile(angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('.someHTMlElement')))(this.$scope);
this.$scope.$apply();

can anyone suggest how to do this in Angular 2+

Comment: basically you can't, angular new generation doesn't compile native html as angularjs does. Could you please create stackblitz example of your actual facing issue ? Actually are too generic.

Comment: Like @Yanis-git said, you should add a StackBlitz so we can figure out what your actual problem is :)

Answer (score -2):

I guess you are looking for change detection in angular 2+. yuo can do it with ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()

check out this [link](https://blog.angularindepth.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular-8006c51d206f)